# Sending mail using Gmail

Tags: c#, .net, windows, smtp, gmail

```
public static bool SendMail(string toList, string from, string ccList, string subject, string body)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add(toList);
        if (ccList != null && ccList != string.Empty)
            message.CC.Add(ccList);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;

        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Timeout = 30000;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";   // We use gmail as our smtp client
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");


        smtpClient.Send(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code seems ok, but still not working, I am not able to figure out why?
any other way to use gmail's smtp to send mail.

Comment: I think you should try port 495 (for SSL) where do you get 587?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
  EnableSsl = true
};

client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
```

If the `UseDefaultCredentials`  property is set to `false`, then the value set in the `Credentials`  property will be used for the credentials when connecting to the server. Here you set `UseDefaultCredentials` as `true` then it will neglect credentials you given.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with Port 25. It's working for me. Also remove setting of UseDefaultCredentials.

**Update :** Port 587 also working for me. So I think UseDefaultCredentials is only problem in your code. it should be set to false.

```
public static void SendMail(string ToMail, string FromMail, string Cc, string Body, string Subject)
{
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);
    MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();

    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email","password");

    mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(FromMail);
    mailmsg.To.Add(ToMail);

    if (Cc != "")
    {
       mailmsg.CC.Add(Cc);
    }
    mailmsg.Body = Body;
    mailmsg.Subject = Subject;
    mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mailmsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    try
    {
       smtp.Timeout = 500000;
       smtp.Send(mailmsg);
       mailmsg.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue some one can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543233/unable-to-send-the-mailmessage-in-asp-net