# Unable to send the mailmessage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mailmessage

The following code unable to send an emails to customers and it not throwing any exception. The code it not send any email or exception but executed.I am completely new about the asp.net. Some one can help me how to resolve the problem.

**Code:**

```
try
{
    String userName = "ramesh";
    String passWord = "123456";
    String sendr = "ramesh@gmail.com";
    String recer = "customer@yahoo.com";
    String subject = "Comformation ";
    String body = "Dear Customer";

    MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage(sendr, recer, subject, body);

    int PortNumber = 25;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.test.com", PortNumber);
    msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;                                     
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);

    smtp.Send(msgMail);

    MsgLP.Text = "Emailed to Customer..";
    LogInLink.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception ex){
    AuditLog.LogError("ErrorE-mail " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in spam? Is there any security settings on Mail Server ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check the spam security settings on Mail Server?

Comment: How do you know its not sending an email if its not throwing? I suggest your code works fine but an smtp server along the way is not delivering the email.

Comment: I mean in Spam folder of yahoo mail where you are sending email.And   are you using your own mail server or a third party.If you are in office you can confirm from Network Department.

Comment: @Ben Robinson,Where I will configure the  SmtpClient server and how to check the server status

Comment: @MairajAhmad & @BenRobinson: His code was throwing `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.` because he had not set `EnableSsl to true`. I added the line and code works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `smtp.EnableSsl=true` and use port number `587`. Your final code will be this:

```
try
{
String userName = "ramesh";
String passWord = "123456";
String sendr = "ramesh@gmail.com";
String recer = "customer@yahoo.com";
String subject = "Comformation ";
String body = "Dear Customer";

MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage(sendr, recer, subject, body);

int PortNumber = 587; //change port number to 587
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", PortNumber); //change from test to gmail
smtp.EnableSsl = true; //set EnableSsl to true
msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;                                     
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
smtp.Send(msgMail);
MsgLP.Text = "Emailed to Customer..";
LogInLink.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception ex){
AuditLog.LogError("ErrorE-mail " + ex.Message);
}
```

I tested this code with my credentials and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the code in note pad may be comma it came and what is mean by "smtp.EnableSsl = true;" can you please tel me.

Comment: SSL (**Secure Sockets Layer**) is the standard security technology for establishing an encrypted link between a web server and a browser. For more details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: One clarification in "Web.config" file the network host port is 25,Now I will use the post 587 it will work or not?

Comment: You can just check it yourself. Try it with `25` and check if it sends or not. If it doesn't send then try `587`

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
        mm.To.Add("email@gmail.com");
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        string strFileName;
        strFileName = "Uploadfile/" + "200814062455PM_Admin_Screenshot (10).JPEG";
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
        mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        mm.Body = ("<html><head><body><table><tr><td>Hi</td></tr></table></body></html><br/>"); ;

        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = "Candidate " + Name + "  for your Requirement " + Jobtt + " ";
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        object userstate = mm;
        client.Send(mm);
```