# Can't send mail to Hotmail

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have been working on for days for this problem. I have two buttons. One button is  to send mails from **Gmail to Gmail**, another for **Gmail to Hotmail**.
I **can send** mails **from my Gmail** account to another Gmail account but something goes wrong while sending from my Gmail account to Hotmail.

> ..mailbox unavailable server..... server response 5.7.3  Requested
>   action aborted; user not authenticated

After five days I am about to give up.
I have checked releated threads on SO

1. [Send email via Hotmail to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448788/send-email-via-hotmail-to-gmail)
2. [Sending mail using Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550863/sending-mail-using-gmail?rq=1)

Plase don't mark as a duplicate.

```
private void gmailTogmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var c = new MailAddressCollection { txtto.Text.Trim() };
    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtfrom.Text.ToLower().Trim());

    // mail.To.Add((c[0].Address));
    mail.To.Add(txtto.Text.ToLower());
    mail.Subject = "for hilk";
    mail.Body = "some heeeeeee";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtfrom.Text.Trim(), txtpass.Text.Trim()),
        EnableSsl = true
    };

    smtp.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}

private void gmailToHotmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("mailSento@hotmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Your Sub";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        //string htmlBody;
        //htmlBody = "HTML code";
        //mail.Body = htmlBody;
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 5000;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "Pass");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not using Gmail at all in your `gmailToHotmail` method

Comment: Just forgot to change the method name

Comment: I've just sent several emails to myself using your code.
Try to specify login and password explicitly and see if it works.
I used it like "mynamehere@hotmail.com" and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you @Fedor but nothing changed I Edited my question like you suggested

Comment: How can you login to **live.com** with an account at **gmail.com**?  Is this really possible?

Comment: Thank you fedor I just found my mistake with your help I feel so stupid

Comment: you're welcome. And don't feel yourself stupid - we all do silly mistakes in the beginning